# imagecreatefrompng error - how to detect and handle?

Tags: php, error-handling, gd, imagecreatefrompng

In my script, I have the following lines:

```
$test = @imagecreatefrompng($name);
if ($test) { ... }
```

I am certain that `$name` represents an existing file on the disk, but I must handle cases where that file is not a valid PNG file (either because of a transfer error or because of a malicious user). I wish to handle such cases by not doing anything at all.

However, given the above code, my PHP interpreter stops on the first line with the following error message:

> imagecreatefrompng() [function.imagecreatefrompng]: 'foobar.png' is not a valid PNG file

Shouldn't '`@`' have suppressed this error message and had the function return `false`as described in the documentation? How can I tell PHP that I know an error might happen and *not* interrupt the execution?

Comment: Does http://fi2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php#98895 help - are you using a custom error handler or something? If for some reason it absolutely won't work, you can always use output buffering to catch the error message, but that's a bit ugly.

Comment: did you try : try catch issue ?

Comment: @Shaddika: you might want to post this as an answer, so that I may accept it. @Haim Evgi: it's not an exception.

Comment: I'm not sure that try/catch would work as an exception isn't being thrown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `mime_content_type` on the file.

```
$image = 'file.png';
if(is_file($image) && mime_content_type($image_type) == 'image/png'){
    // Image is PNG
}else{
    // Not PNG
}
```

This will ensure the image is a file and a PNG.

Comment: Good stuff, does this do everything you need?

Comment: Well, the actual issue was correctly identified by Shaddika - there's a bug in my custom error handler that breaks the `@` construct. I've +1'ed your answer and will accept it unless Shaddika posts his comment as an actual answer instead in the next few minutes.

Comment: How does this answer the question on how to detect errors with gd lib..

Answer (score 2):

'@' is designed to suppresses errors, and you probably get the warning message.

You can do that using exceptions, e.g.

```
try {
    $test = imagecreatefrompng($name);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

See more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: The link you provide has a note explaining why your answer does not apply here - "Internal PHP functions mainly use Error reporting, only modern Object oriented extensions use exceptions."

Comment: Yep, but the same note explains how to make it work for "Error reporting" ones.